# How to get month/day to compare with another month/day without year in hibernate criteria using restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    int userId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    String name;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "doa")
    Date doa;
}
```

I have to required those users whose date of birth is today.

How to write method to get all user whose birthday is today using hibernate Criteria and Restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

First you would need a date without time, you can do it easily with this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date today = new Date();
Date todayWithZeroTime =formatter.parse(formatter.format(today));
```

Then you can reference this date to your criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("doa", todayWithZeroTime);
List results = criteria.list();
```

Let us know if this does not solve your problem, good luck!

Comment: we know  date of birth with year  is past date which never come in future so it will return empty list.Here requirement is to compare date with month and day. means 2nd June 1993 will be compare with 2nd June 2015. then it will return user.